# Is there good method to profile the process for large reductions?

Tags: erlang

I found the process reduction is large in our product environment, and the messages didn't decrease.

FYI, the reduction is 10831243888178 and then 10838818431635 after 5 minutes. The message_queue_len is 1012 and then 1014 according to the reduction.

I supposed that the `messages` returned from `process_info(Pid)` should be consumed in the 5 minutes but it didn't. Can I say that the process was blocked by some messages?

I read from the web that one reduction can be looked as one function call, but I don't fully understand it. I'll appreciate if someone can tell me more about the "reduction".

Comment: How do you know that it hasn't consumed (part of) its message queue and new ones haven't arrived?

Comment: @rvirding Because the messages at previous was always there in the message queue. Can I suppose that the messages should be consumed one by one according to the FIFO principle?

Comment: Seeing Erlang has a selective `receive` there is no need consume the messages in the order they arrive, and therefore you cannot just assume that they will be/should be/have been consumed in order. It depends on the `receive`s.

Comment: @rvirding Thank you. Does `gen_server` behavior also depends on the selective `receive`s in the same callback method such as `handle_cast`?

Comment: No, when using behaviours like `gen_server` you lose some control of message processing. There is a top-level `receive` which takes each message as they come and calls the appropriate call-back function, or processes it internally for system messages. You can of course do send and selective receive inside a call-back but you must be careful **NOT** to receive a system message. Using behaviour requests like `gen_server:call` are safe.

Comment: @rvirding Thank you so much. I've fully understood it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reductions** is a way to measure work done by a process.

Every scheduled process given a number of reductions to spend before preempting, in other words before it will have to let other processes to execute. Calling a function will spend 1 reduction, that seems right, but it is not the only thing that spends them, a lot of reductions will vanish inside this function call too.

It seems that numbers you given are accumulated reductions spent by a process. A big number by itself do not mean something at all actually. A big increase, however, means that process is doing some hard work. If this workhorse is not consuming the message queue, a great chance it is stuck inside one very long, or even unending computation.

You may try to inspect it further with `process_info(Pid, current_function)` or `process_info(Pid, current_stacktrace)`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll try with the methods.